# Multithreading with Swift 2.1 - Ambiguous Reference to Member

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift

I am trying to adapt Multithreading while loading an image. I checked the answers on SO and mine is not any different than theirs. But mine is throwing an error:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'dispatch_get_global_queue'

```
func getImg() {

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0) { () -> Void in
             // GET DATA
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    // Update UI
             }           
         })
       }
 }
```

I also tried using `QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.rawValue` and converting it to `Int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a closing parenthesis/comma. You could do something like:

```
func getImg() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0), {
        // GET DATA
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            // Update UI
        }
    })
}
```

Or

```
func getImg() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)) {
        // GET DATA
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            // Update UI
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got a missing comma, try:

```
func getImg() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)) { () -> Void in
        // GET DATA
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            // Update UI
        }
    }
}
```

(and a spare }, at the end, but that just contributes to the confusion.

or, to not use trailing block syntax, use:

```
func getImg() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0), { () -> Void in
        // GET DATA
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            // Update UI
        }
    })
}
```